# Typescript: Import type from package without dependencies from other types in the same package

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I have a NPM package written in Typescript (let's call it `libd`) that offers some classes and types. They are exported in a `index.ts` file like this:

```
export { ClassA } from "./ClassA";
export { TypeB } from "./TypeB";
```

The `ClassA` is using an external dependency (let's call it `depc`) that is set to peerDependencies in the `package.json`. The `TypeB` is just a type without any external dependencies.

In the `package.json` the main field is set to `dist/index.js` (where it is transpiled to) and types are set to `dist/index.d.ts`.

The `tsconfig.json` of the `libd` package looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "inlineSources": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Now I im consume the `TypeB` in another library (let's call it `libe`) without importing `ClassA` and without having the `depc` dependency installed. The `libd` library is installed via NPM and the type is imported like this:

```
import { TypeB } from "libd";
```

The `tsconfig.json` of `libe` is similar to the one from `libd`.

Transpiling this gives me the error `TS2307: Cannot find module 'depc'`.

Now I understand, if I would use `ClassA` I must install `depc` since it imports it. But I'm only using `TypeB` that does not require any dependencies and sometimes types come with the original package.

I could fix this problem by installing `@types/depc` and Typescript would be happy. Code should work at runtime, since no actual usage of `depc` comes from `libe`. But I would rather not install useless packages.

Setting `"skipLibCheck": true` in the `tsconfig.json` of `libe` would also fix the tsc error but I am not sure what negative impacts this would have.

So my question is: Why does typescript check a class from dependency that I am not importing? Is it, because I have bundled all exports of the `libd` package in an `index.ts` file and all imports of those are going through this index file?

Can I resolve this without separating `TypeB` and `ClassA` into different packages? That would make them very small packages and for ~80% of the time they would be installed both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it, because I have bundled all exports of the `libd` package in an `index.ts` file […]?

Yes.

TypeScript compiler sees that you are using the file `libd/dist/index.{js|d.ts}` and starts evaluating its exports. While doing so, it finds out that `ClassA` is using `depc`, and goes for evaluating `depc`, – but it is nowhere to be found (since it isn't installed). That's a definitive error.

TypeScript compiler doesn't check whether you are using `ClassA` or not, it is not its job to perform tree shaking.

Using [`"skipLibCheck": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) is actually a good way of solving this problem, since its description states explicitly:

> Rather than doing a full check of all `d.ts` files, TypeScript will type check the code you specifically refer to in your app’s source code.

… which is ultimately what you want, right?

Comment: Yes we have moved to set it in our tsconfig.json by now. thank you anyway for the explanation.